# Residues of Zeta-like Function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, zeta-functions

I'm looking for the residues of the following function $$s \mapsto\sum^\infty_{m,n =1} (m+n) \left[ amn + (m-n)^2 \right]^{-s}$$
at $s=\frac{1}{2}$ and $s=\frac{3}{2}$, where $a$ is some real positive number.

Yet, I have literally no idea how to precedure here. I tried to rearrange the terms in order to get some well known zeta function but it failed. Is there any useful integral representation or any simple trick I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is just a sketch, for the detail you can find in the reference of Zagier [http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/ValeursZeta/ZetaFunctionRQF.pdf].  Let us denote 
$$f(x,y)=(x+y)e^{-(axy+(x-y)^2)}.$$
Then you can check that
$$F(s):=\sum_{m,n\ge 1}\frac{m+n}{(amn+(m-n)^2)^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{s-3/2}\left(\sum_{m,n\ge 1}f(\sqrt{u}m,\sqrt{u}n)\right)\,du$$
by  direct calculation. Then, from a result of Zagier [page 10th of http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/ValeursZeta/ZetaFunctionRQF.pdf], actually the Euler–Maclaurin formula, we have the following asymptotic expansion: 
 \begin{align}
\sum_{m,n\ge 1}f(mt,nt)\sim&\frac{1}{t^2}\int_{{\mathbb{R}}_+^2}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy+\sum_{r,s\ge 0}\beta_r\beta_sf^{(r,s)}(0,0)t^{r+s}\\
&+\frac{1}{t}\sum_{r\ge 0}\beta_rt^r\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}f^{(0,r)}(x,0)\,dx+\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}f^{(r,0)}(0,y)\,dy\right)
\end{align}
for $t\rightarrow 0^+$, where $\beta_r=(-1)^rB_{r+1}/(r+1)!, r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ and $B_r$ denote the $r$-th Bernoulli number. There we have as $|u|\le 1,$
$$\sum_{m,n\ge 1}f(\sqrt{u}m,\sqrt{u}n)=\frac{I_f}{u}+\frac{c_{-1}}{u^{1/2}}+c_0+O(u^{1/2})$$
with $I_f,c_{-1}, c_0$ be defined as above asymptotic expansion. 
Hence we can obtain that
$$F(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{1}u^{s-3/2}\left(\frac{I_f}{u}+\frac{c_{-1}}{u^{1/2}}+c_0\right)\,du+h(u)$$
with $h(u)$ is an analytic function on $\Re(s)>0$. Moreover, for $\Re(s)>3/2$,
$$F(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\left(\frac{I_f}{s-3/2}+\frac{c_{-1}}{s-1}+\frac{c_0}{s-1/2}\right)+h(s).$$
This means that $F(s)$ can analytic continuation to all $\Re(s)>0$. The following is easy and I omit the detail.

Comment: My previous comment is wrong, it is a one-sided double sum so is not directly related to Epstein zeta (I do not know how to delete a comment). I agree with Zhou's answer.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. The residue at $s=\frac{3}{2}$ is given by $I_f = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+^2} f(x,y) dx dy$, and at $s=\frac{1}{2}$ by $c_0=0$ since $f(0,0)=0$?

Comment: For $s=3/2$ yes (result $\sqrt{\pi}/a$), for $s=1/2$ no, you must take into account the coefficient of $\beta_1t^1$ (again trivial to compute as Zhou says, but I am too lazy to work it out).

Comment: Professor @HenriCohen to delete a comment click the x that appears at the right when you click near your comment.

Comment: @YoungMath It is very strage that the same paper has two errors (the other being the computation of your other question). Are you sure you didn't missed something while writing the functions here on MO? If  they are actual errors of the paper, then maybe some other articles that cite the one you are studying  hve corrected them.

Comment: @HenriCohen: How did you get your result for $s=\frac{3}{2}$? The integral doesn't seem so trivial for me as I thought first. Maybe there are some factors missing? By the way, I missed a factor of 2 above. But that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @YoungMath: write $x+y=((a-2)y+2x+(a-2)x+2y)/a$ and note that $(a-2)y+2x$ is the derivative with respect to $x$ of the exponent, similarly for the other.

Comment: Found the mistake. The wanted residues are twice the residues of the function above. It was totally my mistake, didn't see it. The comments can be deleted. Thanks for your detailed help.